# Can Logic Apps Monitor a large number of calendars effectively?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-triggers

**PROBLEM**
We want to track changes in user calendars, but are concerned with how often we'd need to check 2000+ user calendars (Outlook).

Would the process of monitoring over 2000 user calendars present a problem for our network?

**WORKFLOW**
Trigger (Check for calendar change) -> ACTION (Http: update a DB)

The Trigger below checks a calendar every 2 seconds.  Is there a trigger that behaves like a "subscription" object where it simply handles a change notification?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question about how often to check the calendar events, it depends on your requirement. In my opinion, if you set check event every 2 seconds(it's a little bit more frequent), you'd better check if your logic app set as run in parallel. You can click the `...` button of the trigger and click "**Settings**". Then check if it is same to below screenshot.

[image]

For your question about is there a trigger that behaves like a "subscription". I'm afraid it doesn't exist a trigger which can implement this requirement in logic app. We can also check if any backend api can implement it, we can see the graph api [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example).

[image]
The example in above screenshot is for `mailFolders`, but it's same with events. We can see it is necessary to specify a user(like `me`) or a group before the `/events`. So I don't think we can monitor the subscription events. You can raise a post on Azure [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) page to suggest developer add this feature.